# Need help in tweaking enum lists

Tags: java, enums

I have public enum like below:

```
   public enum stringList1 {
      string1,
      string2,
      string3,
      string4,
      string5,
   }
```

This enum "stringList1" is referred in all over the code more than 100 places. Currently I have requirement to support below list as well.

```
    enum stringList2 {
          string1,
          string2,
          string6,
       }
```

Actually code should pick either stringList1 or stringList2 depending on a condition.
I know enums can not be changed, also changing all over the code to put condition to pick right enum list is very difficult.

Here refactoring will not help, I need to pick either stringList1 or stringList2 at runtime, but currently stringList1 is referred all over the code. One option is putting the condition in all the places stringList1 is referred to pick stringList1 or stringList2, but this is very difficult.

UseCase: This is for backward compatibility, stringList1 for current version, say v2, stringList2 for v1. Data can be operated by V1 binary and V2 binary. Currenty if user tries to create data using V2 binary, it will create data, which is not understood by V1. So in version 2 binary I need to check, if version is 1, I need to used stringList2 else stringList 1

Lets say method method1(), which will create some predefined values with the help of stringList1, here user has access to method1() don't have access to enum values.
so user just simply call method1, I need to find the version, depending on the version, I have to use stringList1 or stringList2 but the problem is stringList1 is used all over the code :( as  Classname.stringList1.values() or Classname.stringList1 in all over the code, for some internal processing

Please advise me how can I proceed in this case.

Thanks in Advance,
Ashok

Comment: Can you clarify your question? It's not at all clear what you actually need to do, or what help you need. Also, re "enums can not be changed," that's a runtime thing. You can add new values to an enum (e.g., change it) at a code level.

Comment: Please post at least 1 of your conditions.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for reply. Either I need to support either stringList1 or stringList2 based on some condition, not both, so I can't add any string to stringList1. Please let me know, still not clear.

Answer (score 0):

maybe using the refactor function (from eclipse - i guess netbeans and others have something like that too) and renaming could help

```
public enum stringList {
  stringList_string1,
  stringList_string2,
  stringList_string3,
  stringList_string4,
  stringList_string5,
}

public enum stringList2 {
      stringList2_string1,
      stringList2_string2,
      stringList2_ string6,
   }
```

hope this helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

In your IDE you should be able to use refactoring to rename one instance and only rename just that instance (without change other enums)

Comment: here refactoring will not help, I need to pick either stringList1 or stringList2 at runtime, but currently stringList1 is referred all over the code. One option is putting the condition in all the places stringList1 is referred, that is difficult.

Comment: Why do you need two different `enum` types?  If they are interchangable, why not have just one?

Comment: This is for backward compatibility, stringList1 for current version, say v2, stringList2 for v1.

Comment: Instead of having two enums, you can have one with all the old and new values.  When the old value are not needed you can remove them.

Comment: Thanks Peter for reply. here is the case:
Data can be operated by V1 binary and V2 binary. Currenty if user tries to create data using V2 binary, it will create data, which is not understood by V1. So in version 2 binary I need to check, if version is 1, I need to used stringList2 else stringList 1

Comment: Or you could use `stringList1` which could be understood by both versions.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9142/discussion-between-soman-and-peter-lawrey)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to keep the enums separate, i.e. not just add all the values together, you could make them implement an interface, e.g.

```
public interface stringListCommon {
}

public enum stringList implements stringListCommon {
  ..
}

public enum stringList2 implements stringListCommon {
  ..
}
```

This will allow you to pass these enums around with the same methods.

Answer (score 0):

The better and modern way(I think you know enum is comming from C) is to structure special class for this operation. I will wrote you an example with playing card suits.

```
public class Suit {
 private final String name;

 private Suit(String name);

 public static final Suit CLUBS = new Suit("clubs");
 public static final Suit DIAMONDS = new Suit("diamonds");
 public static final Suit HEARTS = new Suit("hearts");
 public static final Suit SPADES = new Suit("spades");

/*other code is what you need you need(either final Suit[] 
  or final unmodifiableList to store values*/
```